# How change int to format money ,I use Angular,any idea?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic3

i need set format money in input tag type number,i have an int 2000555 and need show that in the format 2.000.555,53.I use Angular,any idea?

Comment: Did you realize that your title has more text than your question's body?

Comment: Buttered toast Double D.

Comment: @Ele i'm sorry, this issues is make me crazy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd normally use the currency pipe for this:

https://angular.io/api/common/CurrencyPipe